# What lens/focal length for whale watching

Tags: lens, canon

Shooting with a Canon T6i. Going whale watching near Anacortes, WA next month. What is a good lens to use?
I currently have an 18-135mm and the 75-300mm kit lens. Will these be good enough?

Comment: "Good enough" for what? Getting yourself a National Geographic cover, no.

Comment: If I had to bet, I would bet spending money on additional whale watching trips will produce more good whale watching photos than spending the money on a lens that a meaningful upgrade from your current lenses would require.

Comment: from http://www.nationalgeographic.com/travel/travel-photographers-favorite-cameras/  STEVE WINTER, CANON REBEL T5i
Canon's Rebel was the first truly affordable digital SLR. The original six-megapixel camera has been continuously improved over the years and is still one of the best cameras to be had for the money. It's surprising to hear that National Geographic's Steve Winter was named BBC's Wildlife Photographer of the Year for photos shot with Canon's ultimate beginner camera.

Comment: @dav1dsm1th The question is about lenses, not whether an entry-level camera can be used effectively by a highly-skilled photographer

Comment: @dav1dsm1th "Winter will have numerous camera traps set in the field for months at a time, so it's important that the cameras be inexpensive while giving up nothing in image quality." The trap shots made up about 10-15% of his typical *NG* stories. I highly doubt he shoots much of the other 85-90% with a Rebel.

Comment: From #11 of the same NatGeo article as #7 cited above: STEVE WINTER AND TIM LAMAN, CANON EOS-1D X AND 1D C Canon's EOS-1D X is the descendent of Canon's original full-35mm-frame digital camera. But now it's grown into a super-speedy monster, with all the best attributes of the EOS-1D series in a single camera... "It does everything I want it to. Whether I'm trying to capture an animal sleeping or running, it's all at my fingertips. And you can shoot in very, very low light," Winter says.

Comment: My link/quote was in response to an earlier comment, simply to highlight that National Geographic appear to be less critical of the equipment people use than some of the people who "help" on this site.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're asking this question, I'm going to assume you haven't done this type of photography before. Given that fact, your T6i and the lenses you mention won't be the limiting factor on the shots you get. I'm no expert but I've been a few times with equipment comparable to yours and have achieved pictures I'm happy with.

The challenges I found were predicting where the animals would surface, and maintaining a stable base to shoot from on a pitching boat. If you've done this kind of photography less than a few times, I reckon those will be your limiting factors.

My tips for whatever they are worth

1. Set your camera to AF, centre point only. Area AF will be confused by the sea and unless you're very fast at MF they'll be gone before you find your target.
2. The bright surface will tend to confuse your metering, expect to apply some positive compensation, I'd expect a stop or so although best to take some test shots. Consider manual exposure if lighting is consistent.
3. Stand with your feet shoulder width apart and try not to fight the motion of the boat, you'll get less shake by going with it.
4. Where on dry land you would want roughly 1/focal length to freeze motion, remember that you have to freeze the motion of the boat too. I'm not sure what modes your canon has available, on my Pentax I'd set TAv 1/1000 f8 and let the camera handle the ISO, opening the aperture up a bit if I had to to keep the ISO down to a sensible level

Unless you're very lucky, the 75-300 is probably your best bet. I have been lucky enough to want 18mm on a dolphin boat, but only once. Good luck.

Comment: The 75-300 is the worst lens Canon currently sells. A 70-300 or 55-250 would be a much better bet.

Comment: @MichaelClark How much of a factor would the performance of the lens be given other elements such as photographer experience and highly variable conditions?

Comment: @MichaelClark Which 75-300? I have the IS and it’s lovely.

Comment: @SteveIves I'm glad you like it. The 75-300mm IS is not a lens Canon *currently* sells. The optical formula for the EF 75-300mm f/4-5.6 IS USM (1995) is totally different than the optical formula for the EF 75-300mm f/4-5.6 III introduced in 1999 at about 1/3 the price that is the only 75-300 in Canon's *current* offerings. Just compare the two block diagrams at the Canon camera museum: [1995 IS](http://global.canon/en/c-museum/product/ef330.html) vs. [1999 III](http://global.canon/en/c-museum/product/ef349.html).

Comment: @MichaelClark Thanks - turns out I have the EF 70-300mm f/4-5.6 IS USM anyway :-/

Comment: @SteveIves The EF 75-300mm f/4-5.6 III is also the only 75-300mm lens offered in a kit with the Rebel T6i.

Comment: Your [EF 70-300mm f/4-5.6 IS USM (2005)](http://global.canon/en/c-museum/product/ef388.html) is one of the lenses I mentioned above that would be a better bet than the 75-300. It is the 'descendent' of the 75-300 IS (1995) with an almost identical optical formula.

Comment: I agree that there are better lenses, Canon kit glass is one of the reasons I shoot Pentax, but is that 75-300 really bad enough that in inexperienced hands standing on a boat and stopped down a bit it's still the limiting factor?

Comment: It's a pretty poor lens. The current 18-55mm kit lenses are *much* better optically than the 75-300, which is worse than the original 18-55mm  non-IS kit lenses from 15 years ago.

Comment: Ouch that's pretty damning, thank the Lord for the SMC DAL55-300

Comment: The last telephoto zoom lens I bought (or needed to buy) was the EF 70-200mm f/2.8 L IS II about 6 months after it was introduced in 2010. It's taken a few hard knocks over the years and was starting to demonstrate a pronounced tilt. I finally broke down and sent it in for repair a few weeks ago. Since getting it back from CPS it's like it was when brand new again. It's the best zoom lens I've ever used.

Comment: @JosephRogers In Canon's defense, the EF-S 55-250mm f/4-5.6 is the fairer comparison to the Pentax 55-300, which after all is a crop body lens is it not? The various versions of the 55-250mm are all about as good as the various Canon FF EF 70-300mm lenses but are APS-C only.

Comment: Yes the 55-300 is a crop only lens, the DAL is the budget version which used to be part of the twin lens kit hence the comparison , I'm not super familiar with the Canon lens lineup. The different approaches are interesting between the makes, I have fewer upgrade options but less need to upgrade than if I'd spent the same cash on a Canon setup